# How to get an input list data-value content, after selection ended, using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have defined a searchable select list, as defined below. What I would like is to get the data-value field once a selection is made, while the user will still see the option value string. This field will contain the internal id of the entry.

If I define this id, as a value attribute, the dropdown list will show both the id and the string , and after selection only the id will be visible in the input field.

I've found some posts taking about using data-* attributes to work around this problem, but for some reasons, I'm not able to get this value from the input field, after the selection was completed.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

PS: I'm only interested in pure JavaScript solutions.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function onchangeTest(){
alert(document.getElementById("input").value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="share">
        <input type="text" id="input" list="datalist" onchange="onchangeTest()">

        <datalist id="datalist">
           <option data-value="1">Foo</option>
           <option data-value="2">Bar</option>
           <option data-value="3">Baz</option>
           <option data-value="4">Foo Bar</option>
           <option data-value="5">Bar Baz</option>
        </datalist>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any specific reason you do not want to use `<select>` instead of an input. Because that will solve you problem? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: I need the search functionality too, which the select doesn't offer

Comment: But since this is an input, and a user can also type into this and not select any of the suggestion available via the datalist, i.e i can type "Hello" and your snippet will alert hello. `<select>` does not filter the options based on the a search text. But it still does a search kind of behaviour.. if you type an available option while the dropdown is open it highlights corresponding option.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the options to find the option with a matching value (if any), then read from its `dataset`.

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const option = [...this.list.options]
                  .find(x => x.value === this.value);
  console.log(option?.dataset.id); 
  // may be undefined, as user can manually type text
});
```

```html
<div id="share">
  <input type="text" id="input" list="datalist" />
  <datalist id="datalist">
     <option data-id="1">Foo</option>
     <option data-id="2">Bar</option>
     <option data-id="3">Baz</option>
     <option data-id="4">Foo Bar</option>
     <option data-id="5">Bar Baz</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't do this because datalist content is created dynamically based on what the user is entering, and it gets wiped out once the selection is made.

Comment: I can get it during selection, but I much prefer to be able in a similar way you can get it from a select. Plus the stings might not be always unique.

Comment: @gheorghievgheniev Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do that. The datalist is only for suggestions; it is not a restrictive list of the only possible options.

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler function, you can loop through the options in the datalist, compare the input value with the option's text content, and retrieve the data-value attribute when there's a match:

```js
function onchangeTest() {
  let input = document.getElementById("input");
  let datalist = document.getElementById("datalist");
  let options = datalist.querySelectorAll("option");

  for (let option of options) {
    if (option.textContent === input.value) {
      let dataValue = option.getAttribute("data-value");
      alert(dataValue);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="share">
  <input type="text" id="input" list="datalist" onchange="onchangeTest()">

  <datalist id="datalist">
    <option data-value="1">Foo</option>
    <option data-value="2">Bar</option>
    <option data-value="3">Baz</option>
    <option data-value="4">Foo Bar</option>
    <option data-value="5">Bar Baz</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

I see two problems with this approach

- The `options.textContent` should be unique to always work expected
- Since you are checking `onchange` this might slow down your frontend performance with a large list. If this problem occurs I recommend you to use the debounce technique to prevent excessive function calls while typing.

Comment: textContent is not always unique.

Comment: So there are same options in the datalist for the user? That's an interesting UX. :)

Comment: What I will have to present is some human generated data. So uniqueness on the string field is not guaranteed, nor it is enforced.